# VS Code - ошибка преобразования "тип1" в "тип1" и "перегрузки" функций без перегрузок

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

При написании проекта возникли такие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, что перегружается, т.к. в `vec.h` нету функции `Matrix rotate_z`, такая функция есть в `matrix_functions.cpp`, но ведь *.h файлы это заголовки и в `matrix_functions.cpp` Типы возвращаемых значений такие же. В `vec.h` есть импорт `matrix.h` (в котором ошибка)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это самая непонятная ошибка для меня, даже нет предположений как это появилось. (это `object3d.cpp`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая же ситуация, что и в 1-ом случае.

Проблемные файлы:

- [matrix.h](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1laLo19GlpxaxnDFYHz5jVpDXwAAFAN96/view?usp=share_link)
- [matrix_functions.h](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f0xvt3B5j-A6N0QOxLOj-_2OexCcGV73/view?usp=share_link)
- [object3d.cpp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rSOSvDik_Hfm5S2_xW8cbyDEvsyl9Usm/view?usp=share_link)

Архив со всем проектом - [клик](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wm-2jjaEhWBYkdpzLQgylXWLv-xQBwsB/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: просто добавил блокировку двойного инклуда и вроде компилит matrix.h : `# ifndef  MATRIX_H .. # define  MATRIX_H .. # endif` , vec.h : `# ifndef  VEC_H .. # define  VEC_H .. # endif`
`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а `pragma once` можно?

Comment: конечно, просто я линуксоид

Comment: Да, сработало, с `pragma once`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно избегать двойного инклуда h-файлов, с помощью `pragma once`. Нужно добавить в `matrix.h`: `#pragma once`.

Comment: @NowhereMan, почему, что не так?

Comment: Что значит директива препроцесса? ._ .